# Take each value from same class, make calculations then append it with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to take values from each `.discountPrice span`, convert them to the numbers, make calculations and append them to the `.pSale` tag.
I think that I need to use "this" keyword, but I couldn't integrate this to my code somehow...

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sPrice = $(".productItem .productDetail .productPrice .discountPrice span").text();
  var sPrice = sPrice.replace("$", "");
  var sPrice = parseFloat((sPrice) * 0.7).toFixed(2);
  $(".pSale").html(sPrice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productItem">
  <div class="productDetail">
    <div class="productPrice">
      <div class="discountPrice">
        <span>$25</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="productIcon">
    <div class="salePrice">
      <span class="pSale">
                // This should be 25 * 0.7 = 17.50 //
            </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="productItem">
  <div class="productDetail">
    <div class="productPrice">
      <div class="discountPrice">
        <span>$35</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="productIcon">
    <div class="salePrice">
      <span class="pSale">
                // This should be 35 * 0.7 = 24.50 //
            </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your current approach is that you're working with all the `discountPrice` and `.pSale` elements at once. To fix this you need to create a loop and perform the calculation on each one individually.

One way to achieve that would be to loop through the `.pSale` elements and set their text based on the value calculated from their related `.discoutPrice` element, like this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.pSale').text(function() {
    return (($(this).closest('.productItem').find('.discountPrice').text().replace('$', '') || 0) * 0.7).toFixed(2);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productItem">
  <div class="productDetail">
    <div class="productPrice">
      <div class="discountPrice">
        <span>$25</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="productIcon">
    <div class="salePrice">
      <span class="pSale">
        // This should be 25 * 0.7 = 17.50 //
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="productItem">
  <div class="productDetail">
    <div class="productPrice">
      <div class="discountPrice">
        <span>$35</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="productIcon">
    <div class="salePrice">
      <span class="pSale">
        // This should be 35 * 0.7 = 24.50 //
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this solved my issue.
But I couldn't get why you add " || 0" at the end of first argument of "return". This will return 0 if it can't find ".discountPrice" class?

Comment: `'This will return 0 if it can't find ".discountPrice" class?'` yes, exactly that. If the element is not found it forces the value to be `0` for the calculation to continue without causing an error

Answer (score 1):

While i was writing my answer i saw @RoryMcCrossan excellent answer which should be the accepted answer.

But since i wrote mine i might as well share it (also see my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fu10rc5q/)):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let dPrices = $(".discountPrice");
  dPrices.each(function(index, element) {
    let dPrice = $(element).children("span").text();
    let parsedPrice = dPrice.replace("$", "");
    let calculatedPrice = parseFloat((parsedPrice) * 0.7).toFixed(2);
    $(element).parents(".productItem").find(".pSale").text(calculatedPrice);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productItem">
    <div class="productDetail">
        <div class="productPrice">
            <div class="discountPrice">
                <span>$25</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="productIcon">
        <div class="salePrice">
            <span class="pSale">
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="productItem">
    <div class="productDetail">
        <div class="productPrice">
            <div class="discountPrice">
                <span>$35</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="productIcon">
        <div class="salePrice">
            <span class="pSale">
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```